# Cannot get all site collection users using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection

I am an admin of a new site collection in a SharePoint Online environment, and I can see all the users in user pickers.

However, if i want to get the users in CSOM, i.e: 
`var users = context.Web.SiteUsers;` (where Web is the site collection), it will return only 5 or 6 users, whereas there are really more than 2000 users.

If I create a new element in any list, and selected/resolved a user in the user picker, he will be added to the SiteUsers => I can get the user in CSOM.

On the other hand, I can get all users from the root site www.{mydomain}.sharepoint.com using CSOM.

Any ideas? is there a special permission/configuration that I have to ask for?

Thanks

Comment: Found similar question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207968/i-want-the-list-of-licensed-user-in-office-365-sharepoint-online-tenant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every site collection has its own user database. It's basically just a list at ~sitecollection/_catalogs/users. The Web.SiteUsers collection will only return users who have actually visited the site collection at least once. It's also possible to programmatically add users using the [Web.EnsureUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.ensureuser.aspx) method.

To find all users in your Office 365 Tenant you need to query them through the [Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io). With REST it's possible with this query:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenantid>/users?api-version=1.6
```

where <tenantid> is the GUID of your tenant.

Answer (score 4):

In People Picker, All users are coming from AD whichever selected during User Profile Synchronization Connection.

In CSOM code, "var users = context.Web.SiteUsers;" User are coming which are added in User Information List.

If you want user then you will need to add user into that list.