# I want the list of licensed user in office 365 SharePoint Online Tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, sharepoint-rest-api

```
var items;
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://my365Site.sharepoint.com' + "/_api/web/siteusers",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function(data) {
         items=data.d.results;

        for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        console.log(items[i].Title);
            if(items[i].Email){
            //console.log(items[i].Title+"-"+items[i].Email);
            }}

    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Using this i am able to get all the user list but not able to identify which user having the licence and which one not.

Comment: Similar question asked yesterday: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207846/cannot-get-all-site-collection-users-using-csom/207852

Answer (score 2):

You can use  powershell to get license information:

```
#Connecting to Azure Active Directory

#This first command will import the Azure Active Directory module into your PowerShell session.
Import-Module MSOnline

#Capture administrative credential for future connections.
$credential = get-credential

#Establishes Online Services connection to Azure Active Directory  
Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential

Get-MsolUser | Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE" -and $_.Licenses[0].ServiceStatus[3].ProvisioningStatus -ne "Disabled" } | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, DisplayName,{$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId} | Export-Csv c:\LicensedUsers.csv
```

Reference - [Report on O365 users](http://powershell.office.com/script-samples/report-on-o365-licensed-users)

**edit**

Or you can also try using the Graph API (probably need Azure AD permission, not very sure).

First make the request to get all subscribes SKUs as below:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenantid>/subscribedSkus?api-version=1.6
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscribedSkus
```

After that make a request to get all users as below:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<tenantid>/subscribedSkus?api-version=1.6
```

or (below works for me,but its still in beta)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users
```

The response should be something as below:

```
  {
        "id": "cf4abbb5-73dd-4ba6-8411-731ec326bb17",
        "accountEnabled": true,
        "assignedLicenses": [
            {
                "disabledPlans": [],
                "skuId": "8601034c-e1a0-4176-acb5-f25f5a323116"
            },
            {
                "disabledPlans": [],
                "skuId": "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900"
            }
        ],
        "assignedPlans": [
            {
                "assignedDateTime": "2016-11-29T22:25:04Z",
                "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
                "service": "PowerAppsService",
                "servicePlanId": "c68f8d98-5534-41c8-bf36-22fa496fa792"
            },
            {
                "assignedDateTime": "2016-11-29T22:25:04Z",
                "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
                "service": "ProcessSimple",
                "servicePlanId": "76846ad7-7776-4c40-a281-a386362dd1b9"
            },
```

The SkuId of 'assignedlicenses' will match a license retrieved from the first request.

Reference - [Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/)

Comment: Thanks @Gautam But i want to get this in JSOM OR in REST because i need to run this in SharePoint Hosted App.

Comment: Check updated answer . Not sure why you need it using SP hosted app, would be better if you use powershell, this will take more processing time i believe.